# nginx reverse proxy fix remote url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a wordpress site on different machine behind nginx reverse proxy. The remote host is 10.0.1.1/kehitys/testi/wordpress and I would like to serve this out as www.host.com/. Is there some way to configure nginx to remove the /kehitys/testi/wordpress/ from the URLs and such returned by the remote server?

My config looks like this:

```
location / {
    rewrite /(.*)   /kehitys/testi/wordpress/$1 break;
    proxy_pass      http://10.0.1.10;
    proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect    http://10.0.1.10/kehitys/testi/wordpress/ /;
    proxy_bind 10.0.1.1;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
}
```

Comment: You really should set the correct URL in WordPress.

Comment: agreed.... you can rewrite in nginx but best to configure wordpress correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course!

I do the same kind of thing all the time myself -- much easier to accomplish with nginx than to configure some third-party software up the stream!

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://10.0.1.10/kehitys/testi/wordpress/;
    proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location /kehitys/testi/wordpress/ {
    rewrite ^/kehitys/testi/wordpress/(.*)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, although this is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What were you looking for?  This is exactly what you've asked.  If you also want to automatically modify HTML of the replies on the fly, you could use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter, which would probably require you to recompile nginx.  Then within `location /` as above, you'd add something like `sub_filter_once off; sub_filter /kehitys/testi/wordpress/ /;`